# check a list how many is positive number

Tags: java, string, loops

Write a program called PositiveNegative that reads an unspecified number of integers, determines how many positive and negative values have been entered, and computes the sum and average of the input values (not counting zeros). The reading of input ends when the user enters 0 (zero). Display the number of positive and negative inputs, the sum and the average. The average should be computed as a floating-point number. Design the program such that it asks the user if they want to continue with new inputs after each set of entries, ending the program only when they do not respond to the question with "yes".

Here is a sample run:

```
Input a list of integers (end with 0): 1   2   -1   3   0

# of positive inputs:   3
# of negative inputs:   1
The total:              5.0
The average:            1.25

Would you like to continue with new inputs? yes
Input a list of integers (end with 0): 0

No numbers were entered except 0

Would you like to continue with new inputs? no
```

and here is my code：

```
import java.util.*;

public class PositiveNegative
{
  public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String answer;
      int countpositive = 0;
      int countnegative = 0;
      int total = 0;
      int num = 0;

      System.out.print("Input a list of integers (end with 0): ");

      do{
         String list = input.nextLine();

         for(int i = 0; ; i=i+2 ){
            num = Integer.parseInt(list.substring(i,i+1));

            if( num == 0)
               break;
            else if ( num > 0)
               countpositive++;
            else if ( num < 0)
               countnegative--;
            total = total + num;
            }
            double average = total/(countpositive + countnegative); 
            System.out.println("# of positive inputs: "+countpositive);
            System.out.println("# of negative inputs: "+countnegative);
            System.out.println("The total: "+total);
            System.out.println("The average"+average);
            System.out.println("\n ");
            System.out.print("Would you like to continue with new inputs? ");
            answer = input.next();

         }while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));

       }
   }
```

I can compile file, but when i run it, i can't get result like sample run.

Comment: So what is the problem/question that you have?

Comment: when i run the code , i can not get result like sample run

Comment: You have to provide what you have tried and your program's output or exception stack trace. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You are **decrementing** (`countnegative--;`) the count of negative integers instead of **incrementing** it (`countnegative++;`) when a negative integer is encountered.

Comment: thx i fix it . but still have something wrong in my code